# Change the first cell of a table

Tags: tables

I have this code of a table that have been generated from a matlab script:

```
\begin{tabular}{|>{\columncolor{red!20}}l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\rowcolor{blue!20} P \textbackslash I& \textbf{Net10}&\textbf{Net11}&\textbf{Net12}&\textbf{Net13}&\textbf{Net14}&\textbf{Net15}&\textbf{all-to-all}\\\hline
\textbf{Net10}&\cellcolor{green}68.82&47.31&24.02&20.87&12.84&12.37&30.94\\\hline
\textbf{Net11}&31.06&\cellcolor{green}32.67&17.48&14.13&8.72&8.25&21.19\\\hline
\textbf{Net12}&15.06&12.76&\cellcolor{green}10.49&5.89&5.86&5.76&8.85\\\hline
\textbf{Net13}&9.45&7.08&4.94&\cellcolor{green}4.49&3.72&3.53&5.01\\\hline
\textbf{Net14}&6.56&4.95&3.80&3.27&\cellcolor{green}3.01&2.83&3.86\\\hline
\textbf{Net15}&5.59&4.20&3.34&2.90&2.69&\cellcolor{green}2.50&3.72\\\hline
\textbf{all-to-all}&2.70&2.40&1.86&1.79&1.84&1.74&\cellcolor{green}2.04\\\hline
\end{tabular}
```

How can update this code for change the first cell as depict in the follow figure
[image]

Comment: Please add a so called Minimal Working example.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! To expand on Peter's comment, it is better to post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that starts with a `\documentclass` command, has a minimal preamble and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. Unless the problem is a compilation error, the code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much more likely that they will!

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to change... and why not just edit the value you need ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your objective correctly, you're looking to (a) introduce a long diagonal "slash" line and (b) use different colors in triangle-shaped halves of the top-left cell.

The [diagbox](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/diagbox) package -- a recently-created successor to the `slashbox` package, which is no longer in the TeXlive and MikTeX distributions because of an unclear software license -- and its `\diagbox` macro will help you draw a diagonal slash in a "cell". Unfortunately, I don't think `\diagbox` will let you use commands such as `\cellcolor` to fill in an entire triangle-shaped region.

My main reason for writing up this answer is the following: What are you trying to achieve -- other than, perhaps, create a gaudy or even carnival-like impression -- by using colors (and why red, blue, and green?) for the header row, the left-hand-most column, and the elements on the diagonal, while simultaneously endowing the table with a strong "prison cell" look? (Just looking at all those vertical and horizontal bars gives me claustrophobia...) As your table stands, there's a very good chance that readers will remember it for its gaudy prison-cell look, whether that's intended or not. But will they remember the table's contents? If the latter is among your objectives, I would like to suggest that you spend less (or even no) time on the coloring issues and, instead, provide a more-structured layout for the header material, align the numbers on their decimal markers, use far fewer lines, and give equal widths to all seven data columns. (As of now, the right-hand most column is quite a bit wider than the others; is that intentional or accidental?)

The following screenshot uses the `tabularx` package to create seven equal-width data columns, the `siunitx` package to align the numbers on the decimal markers, and the `booktabs` package to draw only a few, but well-spaced horizontal lines and to provide some visual structure to the header material. Do be kind to your readers and be more explicit about what "P" and "I" stand for. Finally, note the (deliberate!) absence of colors or bold-facing; if you really believe that it's important to highlight a few diagonal cells, you're of course free to do so.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % not really needed in what follows
\usepackage{tabularx,siunitx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered version of 'X' column type
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l *{7}{S[table-format=2.2]} }
\toprule
P & \multicolumn{7}{c@{}}{I} \\  
\cmidrule(l){2-8}
& \mc{Net10}&\mc{Net11}&\mc{Net12}&\mc{Net13}&\mc{Net14}
& \mc{Net15}&\mc{\mbox{all-to-all}}\\
\midrule
Net10&68.82&47.31&24.02&20.87&12.84&12.37&30.94\\
Net11&31.06&32.67&17.48&14.13&8.72&8.25&21.19\\
Net12&15.06&12.76&10.49&5.89&5.86&5.76&8.85\\
Net13&9.45&7.08&4.94&4.49&3.72&3.53&5.01\\
Net14&6.56&4.95&3.80&3.27&3.01&2.83&3.86\\
Net15&5.59&4.20&3.34&2.90&2.69&2.50&3.72\\
all-to-all&2.70&2.40&1.86&1.79&1.84&1.74&2.04\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{diagbox} %<-- added
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|>{\columncolor{red!20}}l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \rowcolor{blue!20} \diagbox[width=2cm]{\ }{\ } & \textbf{Net10}&\textbf{Net11}&\textbf{Net12}&\textbf{Net13}&\textbf{Net14}&\textbf{Net15}&\textbf{all-to-all}\\\hline %<--- new line
    % \rowcolor{blue!20} P \textbackslash I& \textbf{Net10}&\textbf{Net11}&\textbf{Net12}&\textbf{Net13}&\textbf{Net14}&\textbf{Net15}&\textbf{all-to-all}\\\hline %<--- old line
    \textbf{Net10}&\cellcolor{green}68.82&47.31&24.02&20.87&12.84&12.37&30.94\\\hline
    \textbf{Net11}&31.06&\cellcolor{green}32.67&17.48&14.13&8.72&8.25&21.19\\\hline
    \textbf{Net12}&15.06&12.76&\cellcolor{green}10.49&5.89&5.86&5.76&8.85\\\hline
    \textbf{Net13}&9.45&7.08&4.94&\cellcolor{green}4.49&3.72&3.53&5.01\\\hline
    \textbf{Net14}&6.56&4.95&3.80&3.27&\cellcolor{green}3.01&2.83&3.86\\\hline
    \textbf{Net15}&5.59&4.20&3.34&2.90&2.69&\cellcolor{green}2.50&3.72\\\hline
    \textbf{all-to-all}&2.70&2.40&1.86&1.79&1.84&1.74&\cellcolor{green}2.04\\\hline
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see you couldn't get `\diagbox` to color the two triangle areas differently either. :-(

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want to fill two triangle-shaped regions in the first cell, you can use `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` and TikZ.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{>{\bfseries}lccccccc}[hvlines]
\CodeBefore
  \cellcolor{green!15}{2-2,3-3,4-4,5-5,6-6,7-7,8-8}  
  \rectanglecolor{blue!15}{1-2}{1-8}
  \rectanglecolor{red!15}{2-1}{8-1}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill [blue!15] (1-|1) -- (2-|2) -- (1-|2) -- cycle ; 
    \fill [red!15] (1-|1) -- (2-|1) -- (2-|2) -- cycle ; 
    \draw (1-|1) -- (2-|2) ; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\Body
\RowStyle{\bfseries}
\rule[-3mm]{0pt}{1cm}
            &Net10&Net11&Net12&Net13&Net14&Net15&all-to-all\\
  Net10     &68.82&47.31&24.02&20.87&12.84&12.37&30.94     \\
  Net11     &31.06&32.67&17.48&14.13& 8.72& 8.25&21.19     \\
  Net12     &15.06&12.76&10.49& 5.89& 5.86& 5.76& 8.85     \\
  Net13     & 9.45& 7.08& 4.94& 4.49& 3.72& 3.53& 5.01     \\
  Net14     & 6.56& 4.95& 3.80& 3.27& 3.01& 2.83& 3.86     \\
  Net15     & 5.59& 4.20& 3.34& 2.90& 2.69& 2.50& 3.72     \\
  all-to-all& 2.70& 2.40& 1.86& 1.79& 1.84& 1.74& 2.04     \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

So far I managed to achieve half of the desired goal. Method: drawing two coloured triangles in TikZ... sounds simple?

The problem is suppressing the `\tabcolsep`s in the first column, not in the other ones. Like making a drawing touch the borders. While some of the vertical spacing went away with `\smash`, I an still struggling with the remaining horrors, so any help. Oh, and `@{}` breaks the colouring, making stripes of white appear at the cell margins.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath} % to redefine \smash
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\mybox}[2]{\mbox{\smash[b]{\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=#1, yscale=#2] %
\fill[fill=red!20] (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,0) -- cycle; %
\fill[fill=blue!20] (1,1) -- (0,1) -- (1,0) -- cycle; %
\node[text width=12pt] at (0.15,0.3) {A}; %
\node[text width=12pt] at (0.85,0.7) {B}; %
\end{tikzpicture}}} %
}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{>{\columncolor{red!20}}l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
    \hline
    \rowcolor{blue!20} \mybox{1.5}{0.6} & \textbf{Net10}&\textbf{Net11}&\textbf{Net12}&\textbf{Net13}&\textbf{Net14}&\textbf{Net15}&\textbf{all-to-all}\\\hline
    \textbf{Net10}&\cellcolor{green}68.82&47.31&24.02&20.87&12.84&12.37&30.94\\\hline
    \textbf{Net11}&31.06&\cellcolor{green}32.67&17.48&14.13&8.72&8.25&21.19\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

So... The smell of victory is near. How do I suppress those without breaking the colouring with `@{}`s?